# Can Change the Record Title?

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there a way to change the title of the New record form during onload? Like the example below:

[image]

Instead of "New Customer", I want to display "Internal Customer". and it can be changed to another title depending on where the creation was triggered.

Thanks,

dalday

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no supported way of changing this for new, unsaved records.

The only supported way is to set the value of the primary field and save the record.

Answer (score 0):

No supported way of updating the form title. Form title is usually set with the primary field on the entity.

**Unsupported solution:**

Updating the heading html element of the form title element updates the form title. But this needs to be done after a certain time out to allow turbo forms to update the form title.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    var formTitle = jQuery("#FormTitle", window.parent.document);
    if (!formTitle || formTitle.length === 0) return;
    var h1Element = formTitle.find('h1');
    if (h1Element || h1Element.length === 0) {
        h1Element.html('Foo Bar');
    }
}, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any supported way to do this.
   If you are using [CRM 2015 with Update 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2015/04/29/microsoft-dynamics-crm-online-2015-update-1-new-form-rendering-engine/), then manipulating the html DOM is also not advisable because of the new rendering engine. You can still do so if you really wish to by setting the **use Legacy Form to Yes** under the CRM System Settings .

Answer (score -2):

try this on the `Form Load` event:

```
if(Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType()==1)
{
  Xrm.Page.getAttribute("primaryField").setValue('Internal Customer');
}
```